# How to calculate any negative number to the power of some fraction in R?

Tags: r

In the following code:

```
(-8/27)^(2/3)
```

I got the result `NaN`, despite the fact that the correct result should be `4/9` or `.444444...`.

So why does it return NaN? And how can I have it return the correct value?

Comment: In theory, you can't really raise a negative number to a non integer power. Think about what `(-1)^1.5` really means, for example. Any non integer power will require complex root.

Comment: So to be mathematically consistent, IMO, you should keep the negative outside the parentheses (or break up the operations as shown below)

Comment: So you mean I should write `-(8/27)^(2/3)`? Then the answer becomes `-4/9`, not `4/9`.

Comment: You would have to distribute the numerator of the power as well (so technically it's the same thing as below) `(-1) ^ 2 * (8/27)^(2/3)`

Comment: @SeñorO -- [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers/317546#317546]) for a discussion of one meaning of exponentiation under which the OP's question can be answered without involving complex numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As documented in `help("^")`:

> Users are sometimes surprised by the value returned, for example
>   why ‘(-8)^(1/3)’ is ‘NaN’.  For double inputs, R makes use of IEC
>   60559 arithmetic on all platforms, together with the C system
>   function ‘pow’ for the ‘^’ operator.  The relevant standards
>   define the result in many corner cases.  In particular, the result
>   in the example above is mandated by the C99 standard.  On many
>   Unix-alike systems the command ‘man pow’ gives details of the
>   values in a large number of corner cases.

So you need to do the operations separately:

```
R> ((-8/27)^2)^(1/3)
[1] 0.4444444
```

Comment: So the OP would want to first square it, and _then_ take the cube root, if they want 4/9.

Comment: And what should it output? There is no real cubic root of -8/27

Comment: @Metrics: yes, because you're still trying to raise a negative number to a non-integer power. `man pow` says: "If x is a finite value less than 0, and y is a finite noninteger, a domain error occurs, and a NaN is returned." (where x is the base and y is the exponent).

Comment: So, this is not applicable when you have odd power in the beginning. As you can see `((-8/27)^3)^(1/3)[1] NaN ((-8/27)^4)^(1/3)
[1] 0.1975309
> ((-8/27)^5)^(1/3)
[1] NaN
> ((-8/27)^1)^(1/3)
[1] NaN`. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: and to return the fraction you can use `MASS::fractions`

Comment: @SeñorO sure there is -  `-2/3`

Comment: I guess there's not cubic root of the floating point operation of -8/27 :)

Comment: There's something wrong with the algebraic operations demonstrated in your response: unless I'm missing something, you can't factor powers in that way, or else `-1 = -1^1 = -1^(2/2) = (-1^2)^(1/2) = 1^(1/2) = 1`

Comment: OK, sorry for  the downvote (now locked in). Turns out that, under one interpretation of the exponentiation operator, this kind of operation is allowed *for fractional exponents with odd denominators*. That definition (which I think is pretty rinky-dink) by construction excludes the kind of example I picked. [This math.stackexchange.com answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers/317546#317546) does a nice job of distinguishing three different commonly used meanings of exponentiation; the second is the one used in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the operation in the complex domain, which R does support:

```
 (-8/27+0i)^(2/3)
[1] -0.2222222+0.3849002i
```

Test:

```
> ((-8/27+0i)^(2/3) )^(3/2)
[1] -0.2962963+0i
> -8/27  # check
[1] -0.2962963
```

Furthermore the complex conjugate is also a root:

```
(-0.2222222-0.3849002i)^(3/2)
[1] -0.2962963-0i
```

To the question what is the third root of -8/27:

```
polyroot( c(8/27,0,0,1) )
[1]  0.3333333+0.5773503i -0.6666667-0.0000000i  0.3333333-0.5773503i
```

The middle value is the real root. Since you are saying -8/27 = x^3 you are really asking for the solution to the cubic equation:

```
 0 = 8/27 + 0*x + 0*x^2 + x^2
```

The `polyroot` function needs those 4 coefficient values and will return the complex and real roots.

Comment: If you go messing with magic , er,  mathematics, that you don't understand, sometimes goblins pop out of other dimensions that you weren't aware of.