# Why I cannot integrate around zero from a distribution in R?

Tags: r, integration, distribution

I have a distribution function that I need risk adjust it by a coefficient. This risk-adjustment needs to be normalized to be sure that the result is a PDF too. As a simple example, assume that our first PDF is a normal:

```
Qpdf <- function(r) dnorm(r , 0 ,1)
```

Then I have this risk adjustment:

```
RRA <- 0.7
norINTEG <- function(r)   Qpdf(r) * r^(RRA) 
a <- integrate( norINTEG ,  -Inf , Inf )[[1]] 
realPDF <- function(r)  norINTEG(r) / a
```

But the integral `a` and as a result the `realPDF` is not working with this error:

```
Error in integrate(norINTEG, -Inf, Inf) : non-finite function value
```

I tried non-finite intervals like (-2,2), but still, it is not working.

I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Your function is not defined for negative values. To compute `norINTEG(-0.5)` you would need to compute `(-0.5)^0.7`    but that returns NaN

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the *norINTEG* function. it is undefined for negative values of *r*. (as noted byG5W too)

Major issue is with *r^RRA*. when r is negative, for eg (-1)^0.7, is not defined for even denominator in fraction i.e (-1)^**(7/10)**. Also, as you are dealing with pdf, you would require this value to be non negative too.

Assuming you are looking for symmetric pdf. One work around would be to convert it into a non negative number before exponentiation by a fraction use:

```
# (-1)^0.7 = (-1)^70/100 = ((-1)^70)^(1/100)

norINTEG <- function(r)   Qpdf(r) * ((r)^70)^(1/100)
x = seq(-4,4,0.001)
plot(x, norINTEG(x))
```

[image]

For details look into these posts:
1. [Exponentiation basics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers/317546#317546)
2. [fraction exponent to negative number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437701/how-to-calculate-any-negative-number-to-the-power-of-some-fraction-in-r)