# Negative number to the power of a fraction

Tags: r

I was checking other questions like this one: 
[How to calculate any negative number to the power of some fraction in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437701/how-to-calculate-any-negative-number-to-the-power-of-some-fraction-in-r)
But is it not solving the problem, or I am not understanding it.

The thing is that I want to do the power of a fraction of a whole vector (some numbers are positive and others negative)

```
# This is the vector
> vec <- c(-0.50881, -0.50881,  0.11204,  1.08610)
# When I try to do the whole vector I got those "NaN"
> vec^(2/3)
[1]  NaN  NaN 0.23 1.06
# But if I calculate them individually, it works.
> -0.50881^(2/3)
[1] -0.64
# If I transform numbers to irrational, I got this result (which I don't fully understand)
> (vec+0i)^(2/3)
[1] -0.32+0.55i -0.32+0.55i  0.23+0.00i  1.06+0.00i
```

Any help would be welcome. Actually, the result I aim for is the

```
> -0.50881^(2/3)
[1] -0.64
```

that I get when I do it individually. But I would like to get the whole vector.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: According to [`?Syntax`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html), the `^` operator has higher precedence then the negation `-` operator, so your `-0.5^(2/3)` is being calculated as `-(0.5^(2/3))` instead of what I'm inferring you mean as `(-0.5)^(2/3)`.

Comment: They are not irrational numbers, but complex ones. I suggest you read up about powers of complex numbers. Part of your misunderstanding above is also due to operator precedence

Comment: Thus, I could solve it using ```abs(vec)^(2/3)```, and that is it....

Comment: @CarlosAlcala Can you add that as an answer so it will help somebody else who comes here searching for an answer.